# Changing Class on array based elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I have about 20-100 Elements, each with its own ID "xxx_view_ch_&&&" on the text, wrapped in a outer div with the ID "xxx_view_&&&". I want to change the Class on the Element with the ID "xxx_view_ch_&&&", when the user clicks on the whole Element ("xxx_view_&&&").

I currently use this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#reci_view_01').click(function(){
   $('#reci_view_ch_01').toggleClass('not_active header');   });

  $('#reci_view_02').click(function(){
   $('#reci_view_ch_02').toggleClass('not_active header');   });
   
  $('#reci_view_03').click(function(){
   $('#reci_view_ch_03').toggleClass('not_active header');   });
   
  $('#reci_view_04').click(function(){
   $('#reci_view_ch_04').toggleClass('not_active header');   });
   
  $('#reci_view_05').click(function(){
   $('#reci_view_ch_05').toggleClass('not_active header');   });

});
```

```css
.not_active {
  text-decoration: line-through !important;
  color: darkgray;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.css">

    <div class="ui list">
      <a id="reci_view_01" class="item">
        <i class="remove circle outline icon"> </i>
        <div class="content">
          <div id="reci_view_ch_01" class="header">Test 1</div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a id="reci_view_02" class="item">
        <i class="remove circle outline icon"> </i>
        <div class="content">
          <div id="reci_view_ch_02" class="header">Test 2</div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a id="reci_view_03" class="item">
        <i class="remove circle outline icon"> </i>
        <div class="content">
          <div id="reci_view_ch_03" class="header">Test 3</div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a id="reci_view_04" class="item">
        <i class="remove circle outline icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
          <div id="reci_view_ch_04" class="header">Test 4</div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a id="reci_view_05" class="item">
      <i class="remove circle outline icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
          <div id="reci_view_ch_05" class="header">Test 5</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

I want to make a "ToDo-List" like list where i can choose which items i want to add to a other list. I thought there could be a way within a array but i don't really know much about JavaScript.

Comment: so, your script works like you want it to work, but you would like a more elegant and pretty solution? is that what you are asking?

Comment: you can use jquery selector like find and identify the pattern (end with) and matching pattern bind will suite you to bind the event .

Comment: @mnemosdev yes, cause it should be a little part of a web-app which has to be performant. The problem in this case is, that i work with MySQL Databases where the site is created based on the live-content of the Database. The amount of items can vary from 5 to 200.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this you can use common classes to hook the events to all the `.item` elements. Then you can use DOM traversal to `find()` the required child element.

In this case I added the `reci_view` and `reci_view_ch` classes:

```js
$('.reci_view').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.reci_view_ch').toggleClass('not_active header');
});
```

```css
.not_active {
  text-decoration: line-through !important;
  color: darkgray;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.css">

<div class="ui list">
  <a id="reci_view_01" class="item reci_view">
    <i class="remove circle outline icon"> </i>
    <div class="content">
      <div id="reci_view_ch_01" class="header reci_view_ch">Test 1</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a id="reci_view_02" class="item reci_view">
    <i class="remove circle outline icon"> </i>
    <div class="content">
      <div id="reci_view_ch_02" class="header reci_view_ch">Test 2</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a id="reci_view_03" class="item reci_view">
    <i class="remove circle outline icon"> </i>
    <div class="content">
      <div id="reci_view_ch_03" class="header reci_view_ch">Test 3</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a id="reci_view_04" class="item reci_view">
    <i class="remove circle outline icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      <div id="reci_view_ch_04" class="header reci_view_ch">Test 4</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a id="reci_view_05" class="item reci_view">
    <i class="remove circle outline icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      <div id="reci_view_ch_05" class="header reci_view_ch">Test 5</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```